# Sharepoint 2010 CAML-Query, Retrieve the description of an column

Tags: javascript, caml

Is it possible to retrieve the column description data by using an CAML-Query in javascript?

Comment: No it is not, CAML queries are for selecting content of lists, not meta data

Comment: Ok, besides using CAML-Query's then would there be any other way to get the description of the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to retrieve  site column metadata (eg. description) via CSOM (JavaScript)

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var fields = web.get_fields();
var field = fields.getByTitle('Workflow Name');
ctx.load(field);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {      
       console.log('Description:' + field.get_description());
    },
    function(sender,args) {
        console.log('An error occured: ' + args.get_message());
    }
);
```